# Edit in-place Swing Components

Tags: java, swing

Does anyone know of a Swing component that is spreadsheet like in nature, allows in-place editing and can be bound (in some fashion) to an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not need anything fancy you might use a standard swing `JTable` (see e.g. [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)). It allows you to use in-place editing and you can define your own table model.