# Inline edit component in Swing

Tags: java, swing, components, edit-in-place

I'm wondering an inline edit Textfield for Swing does exist. I googled around a bit and checked all swing libraries which I know, but i did not find such a component. Has anyone implemented such a edit-in-place swing component or does someone know such a project?

I know [this SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941746/edit-in-place-swing-components). but I do not want the "spreadsheet feeling".

--- Edit

Because I was not clear what I mean with edit-in-place component:

Essentially the component should look like a Label, but when I click on the Label, it is replaced with a Textfield. Of course this would be trivial to implement with JLabel and JTextfield, but I want a more sophisticated solution. Here a screenshot from a Javascript when hovering the editable field: [image: Editable Screen]

And here when clicking on it:
[image: Editable Screen2]

Of course I do not want the picklist here, but this is just for visualization. I hope you get the idea :)

Comment: What do you mean with "edit-in-place"? In which place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a JTextField.

1. You can set the text field non-editable and the background to be non-opaque.
2. Then you add a MouseLstener to the component. On a mouse click you set the text field editable and make it opaque.
3. When the component loses focus you reset the properties again. So you would also need to add a FocusListener to the text field.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [`JEditorPane`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) is what you're looking for.